# MYSQL Database - HUE connection fails | Unable to connect to database on host machine1 using credential provided

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hue

I am getting such error while connection Hue with external database (MySql).

Setup Database

Configure and test database connections. Create the databases first according to the Installing and Configuring an External Database section of the ...

Error:

Hue

> Unable to connect to database on host 'machine1.localdomain.com:3306'
>   from host 'machine1.localdomain.com' using the credential provided.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Wrong password?

Comment: @RickJames Hello Rick => We came out with the solution that mysql is not compatible with CDH version 5.15.1 for hue

Comment: According to what? CDH is a very broad range of tools, and Hue is just a Python webserver. If you can connect to your database using Python Django/Mysql tools, then it should work... The error is simply saying either your host address or user are not authorized